# Auslander-Reiten sequence and projective covers

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $R$ be an Artin algebra and let $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ be an Auslander-Reiten sequence of finitely generated left $R$-modules. Is it always true that the projective cover of $B$ equals to the direct sum of the projective cover of $A$ and the projective cover of $C$? Thank you very much.

Edit: I would also like to know the following.

Let $A \to B \to C$ ($B$ can be a direct sum of indecomposable modules) be a mesh in an Auslander-Reiten quiver. Is it true that the projective cover of $B$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the projective cover of $A$ and the projective cover of $C$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you look at any examples? It's true if and only if $A$ is not simple, so you would have found a counterexample by looking at literally any Auslander-Reiten quiver (of a non-semisimple algebra).

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you very much. Are there some references about this fact? I need to cite this fact in a paper.

Comment: The question is equivalent to asking whether the head of $B$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the heads of $A$ and $C$, which can be detected by applying $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-.S)$ to the sequence for each simple module $S$, and by the definition of an Auslander-Reiten sequence, that gives a short exact sequence if and only if $A\not\cong S$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you very much for your proof.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you very much for your help. I have another question. I think that this property is true for the Auslander-Reiten sequence of the algebra $B_{k,n}$ in [the post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374856/references-request-auslander-reiten-theory-of-algebras-like-b-k-n). Does your proof also work for the algebra $B_{k,n}$?

Comment: I don't think the same argument works, as I think the only AR-sequences there are for the category of Cohen-Macaulay modules, which doesn't include the simple modules.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

No,
take $R=K[x]/(x^2)$ and $C=A=S$ the simple $R$-module.
Then $0 \rightarrow S \rightarrow R \rightarrow S \rightarrow 0$ is the Auslander-Reiten sequence of $S$ and the projective cover of $R$ and $S$ is $R$.